# Enviar dados de eventos google calendar via http para servidor em java

Tags: web-service, http, google-calendar

Em meu script [java](/questions/tagged/java) consigo listar os eventos do meu calendário, conforme abaixo:

```
String pageToken = null;
do {
    Events events= null;
    try {
        events = service.events().list(CALENDAR_ID).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CalendarService.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    List<Event> items = events.getItems();
    for (Event event : items) {
        System.out.println(event.getSummary());
        System.out.println(event.getStart());
    }
    pageToken = events.getNextPageToken();
} while (pageToken != null);
```

Eu gostaria de saber como que posso enviar essas informações via *http* para um servidor?